# How to uninstall GmailTex

Tags: gmail, google-chrome-extensions

I installed the app [GmailTeX](http://alexeev.org/gmailtex.html) or [in store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmailtex/gjnmclkoadjdljnfmbnnhaahilafoeji?hl=en) in my Gmail account, but I don't find any button to uninstall it.

Does anyone knows how do I uninstall it?

(Uninstall I mean stop appearing in the Gmail sidebar along with Categories and Circles).

If I go to the app store, it does not show uninstall button, and it is also not an app in "Apps" tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That app installs as a Chrome extension. You simply need to find it in the list of extensions and delete it.